How does Room DB with Flow works?
I’m experimenting with Room and Coroutines Flow observables in a simple project, but I'm encountering an issue where the Flow emits multiple times.
In the app, I’m fetching all data from the user's fixed expenses table (like a monthly streaming service, cable TV, etc.) and observing the Flow in my ViewModel. The DAO returns Flow<List<FixedExpense>>.
In the ViewModel, I’m collecting the Flow inside the ViewModel scope. Inside the collect block, I check if the payment date is expired. If it is, I add a new expense to the Expense table and update the last payment date of the fixed expenses to prevent paying the same expense again in the next check. (There is no issue in the check; I made unit tests before and it worked fine without data persistence with Room).
private fun observeFixedTransaction() { 
    viewModelScope.launch { 
        fixedExpenseRepository.fetchAll()
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .collectLatest{
                checkDueTransactions(it) 
            } 
    } 
}

The problem is that when I add a new fixed expense or start collecting the Flow, it emits multiple times. This results in the check running multiple times, causing a race condition that adds multiple expenses. For some reason, a semaphore inside the collect block doesn’t work.
Why does the Flow emit more than once when I add a new row or start collecting the Flow?
I tried using debounce as well, but it didn't work.
I tried using the debounce, but unless i set the timemilis to something like 10 seconds, it won't work. Also tried to use a semaphore with tryacquire but the collect block ignored the semaphore (it was initilizided inside the viewModel class).

This doesn't seem to be something you should be doing in the first place. If I understand correctly then you want new expense entries to be created even without the user triggering them. When this should happen automatically, why bother to create them at all? There is no new information added, everything can already be derived at any time from the initial payment date. You do not need a database for that.
Even if that would be a valid use case such database housekeeping jobs shouldn't be performed by the view model. The database could do that itself, or at least let the repository handle that.
But with all of that put aside, back to the original question: Since you mention race conditions you probably just didn't perform all necessary updates in a single, atomic transaction. Databases are usually not susceptible to race conditions when properly used.
When you execute the first part of the update you database registers a change and emits a new value into the flow. Then the next part of the update is executed, but your flow already got a new value and the check is triggered again. Depending on the intermittent state of your database this may happen multiple times, possibly even in an infinite loop.
This is a common issue with databases, why several decades ago transactions were invented. A transaction bundles multiple operations on the database in such a way that they are guaranteed to either all execute successfully or none execute at all. That also means you won't see any changes in the database until all operations are finished successfully. This is an integral part of the ACID principle.
With Room you would just add another function to your dao and annotate it with @Transaction:
@Dao
abstract class SongDao {
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(song: Song)

    @Delete
    abstract fun delete(song: Song)

    @Transaction
    fun insertAndDeleteInTransaction(newSong: Song, oldSong: Song) {
        // Anything inside this method runs in a single transaction.
        insert(newSong)
        delete(oldSong)
    }
}

This example is from the documentation, adapt to your needs.
With this the flow would only emit a new value when all database operations are finished. Only then a new value is emitted into the flow and the check would be satisfied.
